# Parse json and based on value return a list of keys

Tags: scala, lift-json

Scala Experts , need your help . task is to parse this json and return list of ModelIds for store 'livingstone' which has 'organic' = true.

In this case only RT001 has organic value as true.Please help.

Note: trying to use existing liftweb library .

```
package Exercises


import net.liftweb.json.{DefaultFormats, _}


object test1 extends App {

  val json_response =
    """{
  "requestId": "91ee60d5f1b45e#316",
  "error": null,
  "errorMessages": [
  ],
  "entries": [

  {

    "modelId":"RT001",
    "sku": "SKU-ASC001",
    "store": "livingstone",
    "ttlInSeconds": 8000,
    "metadata": {
      "manufactured_date": "2019-01-22T01:25Z",
      "organic": "true"
    }
  },
  {

    "modelId":"RT002",
    "sku": "SKU-ASC002",
    "store": "livingstone",
    "ttlInSeconds": 8000,
    "metadata": {
      "manufactured_date": "2019-10-03T01:25Z",
      "organic": "false"
    }
  }

  ] }"""


  val json = parse(json_response)

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val elements = (json \\ "entries").children


  for (subs <- elements) {
    val m = subs.extract[Subs]
    println(s"Subscriptions: ${m.modelId}, ${m.store}")
    println(" k,v: " + m.metadata.exists(_ == ("organic", "true")))
  }

  case class Subs(modelId: String, store: String, metadata: Map[String, String])


}
```

Getting Error. Also need help how to filter based on store=living stone and organic=true .

```
Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for modelId
Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JString(RT001), JString(RT002))) into class java.lang.String
```

Final Working code with help from experts:

```
  val json = parse(json_response)

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats


  case class Sales(modelId: String, sku: String, store: String, ttlInSeconds: Int, metadata: Map[String, String])

  case class Response(entries: List[Sales])

  val json1 = parse(json_response)
  val response = json.extract[Response]

  val subs = response.entries.filter { e =>
    e.store == "livingstone" &&
      e.metadata.get("organic").contains("true")

  }

  subs.foreach(x=>println(x.modelId))
```

Comment: You need to provide more information if you want help. Start by showing what you have tried and what didn't work, Also specify which library you are using to parse JSON. This question is too broad as it sits and will be closed

Comment: I added my try and issues i m facing.

Comment: look into ```circe``` https://circe.github.io/circe/ it is arguably the best way to parse JSON in scala

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json` is deprecated. There is no single dominant replacement for it, you have many libraries to choose from, such as Play JSON, Circe, or uPickle.

Comment: Yes but i want to solve the actual problem. My code is not doing enough. It is supposed to look for a value for one key , then if it exists , look for another value for 2nd Key , if its true, return a 3rd key.

Comment: This is why it's important to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask one question at a time. The reason you are not getting any answers to the second half of the question is because we don't know what this will get parsed into and what interface will be available. Most libraries parse JSON into case classes, after that it is a simple ```.filter().map()``` to get what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When processing JSON it is best to convert the whole structure to Scala and then process the Scala, rather than directly processing the JSON.

So create a `Response` class and extract that in a single operation, and then process the `entries` field as appropriate.

Here is some completely untested code:

```
case class Response(entries: List[Subs])

val json = parse(json_response)
val response = json.extract[Response]

val subs = response.entries.filter{e =>
    e.store == "livingstone" &&
    e.metadata.get("organic").contains("true")
  }
```

Note that this should work in any JSON library that allows you to extract a `class` from JSON.

Comment: Tim Great help . It worked. I have attached the working code . Can you please make it more elegant.

Comment: The final code looks good (except that `json1` is not used and not necessary). It is best not to pack too much into one question, so if you other problems then ask another question and hopefully we will be able to help you out.

Comment: yes that is redundant. How ever one problem with the code is : It depends on json response case class. If json response changes, it will fail. Is there any way , i can make a case class with just the attributes I need.

Answer (score 1):

So, as it was suggested in comments section already, you can proceed with [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) library instead of Lift framework, because it is much more modern and widely used solution.

What you need to do - declare structures, like `case class`'es, which represents your json. It's not recommended approach, to operate over raw JSON - rule of thumb - parse it into some meaningful structure and then work with it.

Along with, structure declaration, you also `Encoder` and `Decoder` for let's say "non standard" cases - like `Boolean` which is `String` in cases of `organic` field.

In your case the code might look like:

```scala
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._

    /**
     * General purpose response wrapper. Entries type might differ, as I can suppose, that's why it is generic.
     * 'errorMessages' - since it is empty array in example, I can only guess about exact type. For sake of example
     * let's say it is strings. And same for 'error' field.
     */
    case class Response[E](requestId: String, error: Option[String], errorMessages: List[String], entries: List[E])
    object Response {
      implicit def decoder[E](implicit d: Decoder[E]): Decoder[Response[E]] = deriveDecoder[Response[E]]
      implicit def encoder[E](implicit e: Encoder[E]): Encoder[Response[E]] = deriveEncoder[Response[E]]
    }

    case class Product(modelId: String, sku: String, store: String, ttlInSeconds: Int, metadata: ProductMetadata)

    case class ProductMetadata(manufactured_date: ZonedDateTime, organic: Boolean)
    object ProductMetadata {
      // Boolean codec required - because `organic` is a string in JSON, which has boolean type
      implicit val booleanDecoder: Decoder[Boolean] = Decoder[String].emapTry(value => Try(value.toBoolean))
      implicit val booleanEncoder: Encoder[Boolean] = Encoder[String].contramap(_.toString)

      implicit val decoder: Decoder[ProductMetadata] = deriveDecoder[ProductMetadata]
      implicit def encoder: Encoder[ProductMetadata] = deriveEncoder[ProductMetadata]
    }

    val json =
      s"""
         |{
         |   "requestId":"91ee60d5f1b45e#316",
         |   "error":null,
         |   "errorMessages":[
         |
         |   ],
         |   "entries":[
         |      {
         |         "modelId":"RT001",
         |         "sku":"SKU-ASC001",
         |         "store":"livingstone",
         |         "ttlInSeconds":8000,
         |         "metadata":{
         |            "manufactured_date":"2019-01-22T01:25Z",
         |            "organic":"true"
         |         }
         |      },
         |      {
         |         "modelId":"RT002",
         |         "sku":"SKU-ASC002",
         |         "store":"livingstone",
         |         "ttlInSeconds":8000,
         |         "metadata":{
         |            "manufactured_date":"2019-10-03T01:25Z",
         |            "organic":"false"
         |         }
         |      }
         |   ]
         |}
         |""".stripMargin

    val parseResult: Either[Error, List[String]] =
      for {
        parsedJson <- parse(json)
        response <- parsedJson.as[Response[Product]]
      } yield  {
        response.entries.collect {
          case Product(modelId, _, "livingstone", _, ProductMetadata(_, true)) => modelId
        }
      }
    println(parseResult)
  }
```

which will produce next result

```
Right(List(RT001))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But i wanted to use already existing library . I have updated the question with my try using liftweb library . It gives the error :Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for modelId
Do not know how to convert JArray(List(JString(RT001), JString(RT002))) into class java.lang.String